# caracteres especiales en kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Hola amigos tengo una pregunta quien me puede ayudar como declaro en kivy los caracteres especiales es decir como en python `#coding: utf-8` como realizo eso en kivy gracias amigos

Comment: ¿Te refieres a kv languaje? ¿Que versión de Python usas?

Comment: si me refiero a .kv utilizo python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay forma actualmente de especificar la codificación a usar cuando se lle el archivo .kv Por lo general, esto no es un problema en *nix, pero si en Windows.

El problema es que `Builder.load_file` usa [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) y `open` por defecto usa la codificación local por defecto, en *nix generalmente va a ser UTF-8 pero en Windows es Windows-1252 (cp1252).

Hay varias [incidencias abiertas en GitHub al respecto](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5154), pero a día de hoy no hay ninguna solución "builtin". La solución más simple y portable es no usar la autocarga del .kv y usar `Builder.load_string` leyendo el archivo con `open` y pasando la codificación de forma explícita.

Es importante que cambies el nombre de tu .ui para que no coincida con el de tu clase App para evitar la autocarga. En el ejemplo siguiente, no debe llamarse `test.kv` o `Test.kv`. Obviamente, el archivo debe guardarse usando la codificación que le pases `open`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

with open("ui.kv", encoding='utf-8') as kv_file:
    Builder.load_string(kv_file.read())

class MainWindow(Widget):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Amigo ahora ahora me esta apareciendo un error con el codigo estaba funcionando a la perfecion y empeso a saltar este error ´
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 130, in __getattr__     
     raise AttributeError
 AttributeError´